# Publishing/deploying artifacts to JFROG in multi module builds

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory

I am working on a multi module project and trying to deploy them to JFROG.

Project Structure goes like this:

```
project
  module-1
    pom.xml
  module-2
    pom.xml
```

In the parent pom:

```
<modules>
module-1
module-2
<modules>
```

I have added `<distributionManagement>` and added the required details to connect to my artifactory.
Verified that there are no connectivity issues to Artifactory.

**Module-1 gives com/abc/def/project/module-1/module-1.pom and com/abc/def/project/module-1/module-1.jar
Module-2 gives com/abc/def/project/module-2/module-2.pom and com/abc/def/project/module-2/module-2.jar**

Requirement: I have to push the above pom and jar of both the sub modules to JFROG.

I am using goal - **mvn clean deploy** from my jenkins pipeline. However it is not working.

Comment: `However it is not working.` what does that mean? Show log output error messages etc... show the project structure

Comment: @khmarbaise There is no error message. Pushing the artifacts to Artifactory isn't happening. Only com/abc/def/project/module-1/module-1.pom is being pushed and the remaining expected 3 files are not being pushed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to use the JFrog CLI. With that, you don't have to configure any resolution or deployment repositories in your pom.xml/settings.xml.

You can do that in 4 simple steps:

```bash
# Step 1: Install JFrog CLI
curl -fL https://install-cli.jfrog.io | sh

# Step 2: Configure the JFrog platform:
jf c add internal --url=https://acme.jfrog.io --user=jfrog_user --password=jfrog_password

# Step 3: Configure the Maven project
jf mvnc --repo-resolve-releases libs-release --repo-resolve-snapshots libs-snapshot --repo-deploy-snapshots libs-snapshot-local --repo-deploy-releases libs-release-local

# Step 4: Install and publish your Maven project
jf mvn clean install
```

Additionally, it is recommended to save the build-info in Artifactory.
To do that, set the JFROG_CLI_BUILD_NAME and JFROG_CLI_BUILD_NUMBER environment variables before step 4 and run `jf rt build-publish` in the end.

Read more:

1. [QuickStart Guide: Maven and Gradle](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/QuickStart+Guide%3A+Maven+and+Gradle)
2. [Running Maven Builds](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningMavenBuilds)
3. [JFrog CLI Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI)